# Zero downtime deployment with Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

The documentation for [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) indicates that a phased restart can be initiated with the USR1 signal. But I am unclear as to how to do a rolling restart using this. If I have directories /home/abc/rails_app and /home/abc/rails_app_updated containing a copy of my code with the new changes, is there suppose to be a way to tell puma where my new code is when doing a restart? I couldn't find anything definitive on this.

Comment: Do you have anything running in front of Puma? Some reverse proxy/cache like Varnish, nginx, haproxy or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puma loads your code when it starts, after that you could delete the rails app and things would still keep working (basically). So you can update the code, and Puma wouldn't even notice. What sending the USR1 signal does is make puma reload the (new) code, while gracefully handling existing connections. So there is no need to have two separate directories, you can update the code in place.

If you do need to separate directories, you can just have a single symlinked directory that points at the code that you want to be current and which is used by Puma (capistrano uses this strategy, it has a symlink 'current' pointing at the latest release). Then send puma USR1 and it will reload the code from the given dir.

please let me know if you need more pointers.

Edit: Probabaly I was not very precise. Puma doesn't actually handle the (re)loading of files, that's handled by Rails (Puma just starts a Rack application, or on a USR1 signal, will restart an application). In development mode, Rails will reload files on every request, which is handy when changing code. On production these settings typically apply (from `config/environments/production.rb`):

```
  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true
```

More details [in the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

If you really want to go down the rabbithole could have a look at what the `cache_classes` does exactly in the rails source, but I'm not familiar with that.

Niels

Comment: The first paragraph is very useful. I could not find any definitive documentation saying that changing code after Puma starts is safe and is what is intended. I will award bounty when time allows.